# Is it ok to use closures for the sake of encapsulation?

Tags: php, closures

I was using a code like that:

```
$a = [];
$a['a'] = 1;
$text1 = [];
foreach ($b as $item)
{
    $text1[] = $item['1'];
}
$a['text1'] = implode(',', $text1);

$text2 = [];
foreach ($b as $item)
{
    $text2[] = $item['2'];
}
$a['text2'] = implode(',', $text2);
```

my colleague rewitten it like that:

```
$a = [];
$a['a'] = 1;
$a['text1'] = call_user_func(function() use ($b) {
    $text1 = [];
    foreach ($b as $item)
    {
        $text1[] = $item['1'];
    }
    return implode(',', $text1);
}();

$a['text2'] = call_user_func(function() use ($b) {
    $text2 = [];
    foreach ($b as $item)
    {
        $text2[] = $item['2'];
    }
    return implode(',', $text2);
}();
```

his reason: it increases encapsulation, and in my first example there will be "strolling" variables (`$text1`, `$text2`) unless I unset them.

Comment: What does this have to do with Clojure. Is that tag a typo for `closure`?

Comment: What about `$a['text1'] = implode(',', array_column($b, '1'));`?

Comment: Your syntax for `call_user_func` is wrong. It should be `call_user_func(function(){...});` You have an extra `(` at the end.

Comment: In two words, your colleague has a point. However, their changes are just a small step towards a correct encapsulation in an object that should contain both `$b` and the just created closures (as methods).

Comment: The usage of `call_user_func()` in the second bit of code is quite misplaced, especially because it is repeated, virtually the same way, a second time. It is much better to use a normal function, once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with your colleague - it makes sense to use closures to encapsulate code.

However, the entire thing you have there can be simplified to this:

```
<?php

$a = [
    'a' => 1,
    'text1' => implode(',', array_column($b, '1')),
    'text2' => implode(',', array_column($b, '2')),
];
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: "it makes sense to use closures to encapsulate code" --- what is the point of doing that? Here it simply to work-around the lack of block scoping in php, nothing more.

Comment: @zerkms You can limit the scope of variables to a closure, rather than scattering the scope where the closure is used. That's the point the colleague made, right? I agree with it.

Comment: And the practical reason for it is...? What problem did it solve? I see the code became less readable, consuming more memory and slower.

Comment: @zerkms Are you referring to my code or the code posted by the original poster?

Comment: Code from original poster (the #2) for sure. Your code is nice :-)

Comment: @zerkms Ha, thanks! Wasn't sure, to be honest. Agree with you that the code example by the original poster's colleague is less readable, that's why I suggested to apply a simpler solution.